# #1054 Unknown Column in Field List in mysql Procedure

Tags: php, mysql

I have table name "tmp1" which has fields name id and comma. comma contains 1,3,2,4,5 values with text datatype.

I want separate value in loop in my stored procedure. Like 1 then 3 then 2 etc. So, I was create below given procedure.

```
BEGIN
DECLARE my_delimiter CHAR(1);
DECLARE split_comma text;
DECLARE done INT;
DECLARE occurance INT;
DECLARE i INT;
DECLARE id INT;
DECLARE sel_query VARCHAR(500);
DECLARE splitter_cur CURSOR FOR SELECT id,comma from tmp1;
DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET done=1;

OPEN splitter_cur;
    splitter_loop:LOOP
        FETCH splitter_cur INTO id,split_comma;
        SET occurance = LENGTH(split_comma) - LENGTH(REPLACE(split_comma,',',''))+1;
        SET my_delimiter=',';

        IF done = 1 THEN
            LEAVE splitter_loop;
        END IF;

        IF occurance > 0 THEN               
            SET i = 1;              
            WHILE i <= occurance DO
                SET sel_query = "SELECT SUBSTRING_INDEX(comma,',',i) as abc from tmp1"; 
                SET @sel_query = sel_query;
                PREPARE sel_query FROM @sel_query;      
                EXECUTE sel_query;                  
                SET i = i + 1;
            END WHILE;
        END IF;
        SET occurance = 0;
    END LOOP;
CLOSE splitter_cur;
END;
```

But when I execute this procedure error occurs "MySQL said: #1054 - Unknown column 'i' in 'field list'"

But here i is a variable used to rotate loop.

Is there any solution? Please help me ... Thank you in advance ...

Answer (score 0):

You have to embed value of variable `i` in the query, which you did not do.

**Change**:

```
SET sel_query = "SELECT SUBSTRING_INDEX(comma,',',i) as abc from tmp1"; 
SET @sel_query = sel_query;
```

**To**:

```
SET @sel_query = CONCAT( "SELECT SUBSTRING_INDEX(comma,',',", i, ") as abc from tmp1 )";
```